# Using __str__ method to return rectangle coordinates

Tags: python-3.x

I'm getting issues like:

```
SyntaxError
invalid syntax (prog1.py, line 114)
```

I get that kind of error when i try to use the **str** method to return coordinates, lenght , widht and color of a rectangle that I already coded.

```
def __str__ (self):
    return ("starting point:""("self.x,self.y")""\n""width:"self.w"\n""lenght:"self.h"\n""color("self.r,self.g,self.b")")
```

Where i should be getting

```
'starting point:(100,20)\nwidht:400\nlenght:120\ncolor(100,255,0)'
```

Answer (score 2):

concatenation of strings (and other types) doesn't work like that in Python

you could do `starting_point:("+str(self.x)+","+str(self.y) ...` but that would be cumbersome.

You need `str.format`, with `{}` placeholders and your data as arguments of the `format` method, like this:

```
return ("starting point:({},{})\nwidth:{}\nlength:{}\ncolor({},{},{})".format(self.x,self.y,self.w,self.h,self.r,self.g,self.b))
```